# Setting order in Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.6

I am a beginner in Python . dont know how can i set the order in Dictionary? . i searched and came to know it could be done through `from collections import OrderedDict` but don't know how to use it. i am trying below mention code to compare two Dictionary but i am not getting the output in order .

```
d = { k[0]: k[1:] for k in a }
d2= { k[0]: k[1:] for k in b }
p = {i:j for i,j in d2.items() if i not in d} 
q = {i:j for i,j in d.items() if i not in d2}
```

Any idea how to do this ?

Updated Question :

```
i have a nested list . How to get each list of nested list in next line ?

[['Eth116/1/12        sales            connected 1         full    10G     Fabric Exte'], ['Eth116/1/13   marketing        connected 190       full    100                ']]
```

Expected Output :

```
Eth116/1/12        sales            connected 1         full    10G     Fabric Exte
Eth116/1/13   marketing        connected 190       full    100
```

Comment: `d = OrderedDict((k[0], k[1:]) for k in a)`.

Comment: dictionaries are unordered, if you want order you need a list

Comment: If you need to retain the order in which keys were *added to the dictionary,* then yes, you need OrderedDict. If you need to order the keys by some function, keep using a standard dict and use `sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda k: d[k])` to get the keys sorted based on their values (or whatever other criterion you need).

Comment: as a beginner in Python, you should concentrate on Python 3. In Python 3.7, dictionaries are ordered, in the C-Python 3.6 (the most common version) they are also ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are unordered and there is not much you can do to change that, short of writing your own subclass of `dict` (not recommended). Using `OrderedDict` will work, as shown in hiro protagonists's comment, as long as you keep in mind that the order in an `OrderedDict` is the *order of insertion* and is not related to the values of the keys. (The same is true of the ordering of Python 3 `dict`s.) If `a` and `b` have the same elements but in a different order then the resulting `OrderedDict`s will not be equal, unless you sort `a` and `b` beforehand.

If you want to compare two `dict`s where you can't easily determine the order of insertion, you need a data structure that supports unordered comparisons. I didn't have your data so I had to make some up. I started with this input

```
>>> a
[[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39], [8, 17, 26, 35, 44, 53, 62, 71], [9, 19, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89]]
>>> b
[[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39], [8, 17, 26, 35, 44, 53, 62, 71]]
```

As you can see, `a` has one extra element beginning `9`.

Modify your dictionary construction code to make the values tuples not lists, because the dict values need to be hashable for the next step to work:

```
>>> d = { k[0]: tuple(k[1:]) for k in a }
>>> d2= { k[0]: tuple(k[1:]) for k in b }
```

Then you can convert the dictionaries to sets to do an unordered comparison:

```
>>> s = set(d.items())
>>> s2 = set(d2.items())
>>> s == s2
False
```

And you can use the set operators to discover what the difference is:

```
>>> s2 <= s
True
>>> s - s2
set([(9, (19, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89))])
```

Comment: so i manage to convert into nested list so that it will be in order. How to get each list in next line ? i have updated the question..

Comment: @Jinni That is a rather different question (nothing to do with ordering `dict`s) but you can output the list you present like this: `for item in mylist: print item[0]`

Answer (score 0):

As of python 3.6 dictionaries are ordered in python, ignore the above answer for pythons above that number!

see [here, on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)